# How to analyse 'than seeing Santa'?

Tags: phrases, clauses

> She was more excited about getting candy than seeing Santa.

1. How is 'seeing' functioning here?
2. How to analyse 'than seeing Santa', is it a phrase or clause?

Comment: haha, I can't help but say this. Santa is a claus(e) ..that's why he's Santa Claus !!

Comment: You might want to check out : http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6359/understanding-a-passage-in-relation-with-clauses-and-phrases

Comment: @VarunKN - and Santa's helpers are called "subordinate Clauses". (0:

Comment: +1 Ho ho ho very good @CopperKettle, and Mrs Claus? A **relative clause**?

Comment: I think this could be seen replacing *than* by *instead of*.

Comment: @Subjunctive - I disagree slightly; *than* and *instead of* don't mean the same thing.  *Instead of* implies she got candy *rather than* seeing Santa, and doesn't quite work grammatically.  *Than* means that both happened, or at least were possibilities, but we're comparing the two things.

Comment: @stangdon Yes. I just realised about that. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

**Seeing** is a *gerund*, which is essentially a noun made from a verb.  Literally, "seeing" means "the act of perceiving with the eyes", but in this case it's slightly more metaphorical and means "visiting".

**Than** is a conjunction, in this case a function word used to compare two different things.  **Than seeing Santa Claus** is a phrase, since it doesn't have its own subject and verb.

Comment: What kind of phrase it is?

Comment: @Onyx - I think "than" is a transitional word into the gerund phrase "seeing Santa".